# Bootstrap sass $theme-colors with rgba color?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass

**style.scss:**

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

$blue:       rgba(#0000ff, .37);

$colors: (
  "blue":       $blue
);

$primary:       $blue;

$theme-colors: (
  "primary":       $primary
);
```

At the end it is not work. I see rgb color. Bootstrap 5.1

How I can use rgba color for $theme-colors (not opacity, only rgba)?

Comment: Please tag your Bootstrap version.

Comment: last version 5.1